# Spring Batch Infrastructure 3.0.8

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Unable to find packages related to Retry in Spring Batch version 3.However, it is available in Spring Batch version 2. Are there any alternate for retry in version 3

Answer (score 1):

Spring Retry is a separate library delivered on it's own (and has been since Spring Batch 3).  You can find it in Maven central here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.retry%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-retry%22